# Ошибка перехода на страницу

Tags: php, wordpress

В своем проэкте пробую реализовать следующий функционал

```
function create_page_on_category_creation($term_id) {
    $category = get_term($term_id, 'category');

    
    $page_title = $category->name;
    $existing_page = get_page_by_title($page_title);

    if (!$existing_page) {
        
        $page_args = array(
            'post_title' => $page_title,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'page_template' => './template-parts/content.php', /* шаблон */
        );

        $page_id = wp_insert_post($page_args);

    }
}

add_action('create_category', 'create_page_on_category_creation');
```

При создании категории, создается отдельная страница. Шаблон для создания страницы берется готовый, в файле content.php, фактически это пробный шаблон, его содержимое используется на другой странице. Но когда я создаю ссылку на новосозданную страницу и пытаюсь по ней перейти, у меня в браузере появляется сообщение об ошибке

```
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
wpsite
Apache
```

В чем может быть проблема.

Я пробовал менять файблы шаблоны, а так же менял пути к ним, но это не помогло

Comment: А чего у вас 'post_type' => 'page',  ? Вы страницу или пост создаете... у страниц же по умолчанию категорий нету.

Comment: Ну как минимум, согласно документации к wp_insert_post вы профтыкали указать параметр `'post_author' => user_id` без которого точно работать не будет.

Comment: Небольшая приметка, поле таблицы `page_template` было удалено, теперь, шаблон для постоянной страницы задается в метаполе `_wp_page_template` — там храниться название php файла шаблона.

Comment: Ещё вижу что тут с назначением категории данному посту какая-та лажа... Как оно должно понять что новому посту надо присвоить данную категорию ? Что-то по типу `'post_category' => array( 8,39 )`

Comment: Каким образом лучше исправить код, чтобы оно работало. Суть в том, что при создании категории, должна создаваться страница, где будет выводиться запись с соответствующей категорией. Чтобы не создавать вручную страницу под категорию, хочу это сделать автоматизированным.

Comment: А для чего вообще создавать страницу под категорию? У категорий есть свой шаблон, где как раз выводятся записи относящихся к этой категории.